# Getting Woocommerce cart ID before checkout

Tags: woocommerce, hook

I am building a PHP $_SESSION array as a user goes thru the shopping process, collecting data about their actions. I want to insert the current cart ID or order ID into the session array so I can tie the two together.

How do I get the cart ID or order iD before checkout, like from inside of woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() or something, so as soon as the first product is added to the cart, it also adds the cart ID to the session?

TL;DR how do I get the woocommerce cart ID after the first product is added, and use that to get the final order ID after payment?

Comment: I feel compelled to ask: what have you tried already? What issue are you running into with your code? There is no order ID before checkout so you're limited to a cart identifier. Each cart will have a unique identifier. Look for an event that's called at the moment you need, e.g. `woocommerce_add_to_cart`, and use that to hook in and do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Inside of woocommerce_add_to_cart I have the $woocommerce object, which I assume is new WC() but every answer on here to get the cart iD requires $post, and that isn't available. Is there a function on WC() to get the cart id?

Comment: Anyone? Bueller?